# Configuration Error while installing MySQL in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2, mysql, sql

Unfortunately, I uninstalled MySQL. When trying to install it later I get this following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
mysqld: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried the following steps

1. Removed MySQL server completely and tried installing again.
2. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
3. `apt-get install -f`

But no use.

Comment: Have you tried running `apt-get --fix-broken install` as it suggests in the error message?

Comment: @SamuelP. Yes, `-f` is short for `--fix-broken`.

Comment: also tried it but not working

Comment: Sorry didn't remember that

Comment: Try deleting the `/etc/mysql*` files and folders then try installing again

Answer (score 0):

Probably your some config files are missing on your system. Run the following command to restore them:

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install mysql-server
```

It is possible, that you get an error at the end of this command, but the folder `/etc/mysql/conf.d/` should be there now. If the command fails, you have to start mysql manually:

```
service mysql start
```

Then run the following, to finish installation:

```
apt-get install -f mysql-server
```